# Dynamic Elements in JSP?

Tags: html, jsp, animation, dynamic

I am wondering how to create dynamic elements in a JSP webpage? For example, what I want to do is that I have a Selection Box, in which a user selects an image. Upon clicking a button (or possibly after selecting an item), the image will 'slide down' (like how PPT slides slide down when changing slides) and rest on the center of the screen.

Or at least another simpler case would be, when clicking a button, a text box will appear each time you click the button. So far, the only idea I have of this is by using visibility but that will limit me.

Can you help me on how to do these things or if it is possible to do these with only JSP? Additionally, is it possible for elements to 'pop up' (like in facebook photo viewer) without refreshing the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You want things to happen on the client, so you need to be focusing on the HTML, CSS and JavaScript. The fact you generate the HTML using JSP is irrelevant.

1. [Build on things that work](https://web.archive.org/web/20160330201653/http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/)
2. Write JS logic for adding new content based on the form options
3. Write JS logic for manipulating the CSS to do the animation

Consider using [a library](http://microjs.com/) such as [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to help with the JS, and using [CSS 3 Transitions](http://www.google.co.uk/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=CSS+3+transforms#pq=css+3+transforms&hl=en&cp=9&gs_id=d&xhr=t&q=css3+transitions&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=CSS+3+tra&aq=0s&aqi=g-s1g1g-s2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=722143ba454bdbd2&biw=1109&bih=705) for the animation.

Comment: Okay thanks, but one question. Should the HTML I generate be created using Servlets or JSP (the <% %> one) because I was told that using Servlets is the recommended practice.

Comment: The choice between servlets and JSP is irrelevant to the question … and something I know nothing about.

Comment: @Quentin this link that you mentioned in your answer is dead. http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/

Comment: @FarazDurrani — Replaced.